# Using proc for class method

Tags: ruby, proc

how do I write a bubble sort that will accept a proc?

it seems like we can't `.call` when writing a method for a class?

help!

```
class Array
      def bubble_sort!
            flag = true
          while flag
            flag = false
            self.each_with_index do |x, y|
              case x <=> self[y + 1]
              when 1
                self[y], self[y + 1] = self[y + 1], self[y]
                flag = true
              end
            end
          end
          self
      end

      def bubble_sort!(&prc)
        # With a proc

      end

    end
```

Comment: "help!" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

The `&prc` in a method signature:

```
def m(&prc)
```

is really just a way to convert the *block* to a `Proc` and give it a name; this is why you usually see it called `&blk` where "blk" is short for "block". You usually do this when you want to pass the block to another method:

```
# This is a highly contrived example of course.

def m1
  # Do something with the "anonymous" block
  yield
end

def m2(&blk)
  m1(&blk)
end

m2 { "This is the block" }
```

So if your `bubble_sort!` method wants to take a block then you would name it all, you'd just `yield` with the appropriate arguments inside the method:

```
def bubble_sort!
  self.each_with_index do |x, y|
    # ...
    something = yield x, y
    # ...
  end
end
```

If your `bubble_sort!` needed to pass the block to another method then you'd say `def bubble_sort!(&blk)` and `some_other_method(&blk)`:

```
def bubble_sort!(&blk)
  self.each_with_index do |x, y|
    # ...
    something = some_other_method(&blk)
    # ...
  end
end
```

and if you also needed to execute the block as well as passing it to another method, you'd treat it like any other `Proc` and say `blk.call`.